# Unable to print required data

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am trying to print the required data using multiple if statement

```
$event_date = '2015-11-16';
//print_r($event_date);
$daily_info = array();
$buk_data = array();

$bw_daily_data = db_query('select * from potli_booking where buk_date   =:buk_date order by refno',array(':buk_date' => $event_date));

foreach($bw_daily_data as $daily_data) {
    $waitlist = $daily_data->waitlist;
    $noshow = $daily_data->noshow;
    $seated = $daily_data->seated;
    if($waitlist == '0' && $noshow == 'no' && $seated == 'NULL') {
        $daily_info['data'][]=array(
            'firstname' =>$daily_data->fname,
            'lastname' => $daily_data->lname,
            'time'=>$daily_data->time,
            'status'=>'overdue  arrival'
        );
    }
    else if($waitlist == '1' && $noshow == 'no' && $seated == 'NULL') {
        $daily_info['data'][]=array(
            'firstname' =>$daily_data->fname,
            'lastname' => $daily_data->lname,
            'time'=>daily_data->time,
            'status'=>'Wait list'
        );
    }
    else if ($waitlist == '0' && $noshow == 'yes' && $seated == 'NULL') {
        $daily_info['data'][]=array(
            'firstname' =>$daily_data->fname,
            'lastname' => $daily_data->lname,
            'time'=>daily_data->time,
            'status'=>'No show'
        );
    }
    else {
        $daily_info['data'][]=array(
            'firstname' =>$daily_data->fname,
            'lastname' => $daily_data->lname,
            'time'=>daily_data->time,
            'status'=>'seated'
        );
    }
}
print_r($daily_info);
```

but it prints the seated data only.help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Have your tried printing your `$waitlist`/`$noshow`/`$seated` after setting them to see what the values are, and why your `if`/`else if` is failing?

Comment: Formatting your code to make it more readable will help others to find problems with it.

What is still lacking from this question is a clear description of the problem you're having. What is "required data" or "seated data"? We don't know this.

Comment: Waitlist has the following three data in the db like " 0,0,1,0 " and   seated has "NULL,1,NULL,NULL"  finally noshow has "no,no,no,yes" these are the conditions. eg :- if  waitlist =0 ,seated = NULL , noshow = no  then it should print "overdue" or waitlist=0,seated=1,noshow=no should print "seated" or waitlist=1, seated = NULL and noshow=no should print "waitlist" these are the conditions